# Static member value being carried to next test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am unit testing a class like below

```
public class A {
 private static String aStr = null;

 public void doSomething() {
    if (null == aStr) {
       // do something to init aStr, and this initialized val gets cached for future calls.
       aStr = some_val;
    } else {
      // do something else using aStr value.
   }
 }
```

Now while unit testing this I am doing :

```
public class ATest {
 private A a;

 @BeforeMethod
 public void setup() {
    a = new A();
 }

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    a.doSomething();
    // assert on some_val being fetched correctly.
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    a.doSomething();
    // assert again for some_val

    // this is where some_val fetching is not invoked at all, while debugging I 
    // can see that aStr is already being initialized from previous test. 
  }
}
```

I was assuming that since i am reinitializing object 'a' in @BeforeMethod setup, i should get null value for all tests.. Isn't this assumption correct?

Comment: Why would a static field be re-initialised by creating a new instance?

Comment: I think you got confused about the meaning of the `static` keyword. It means that a field does not belong to an instance anymore. With `static` it gets a field which is **shared** by all instances of that class. So it's not that every instance of this class has its own `aStr`, they rather all share **the same only** `aStr` field.

Comment: What sense would that make to have static members when a new object resets their values? Java would be logically broken if that were the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` modifier on a field in java means that this field does not belong to a specific instance of that class, but to a class itself. In most cases you have only exemplar of the class in the running JVM. So it does not matter how many objects of this class you create - they all will share one and the same static field. And one and the same value of that field

Comment: Ohh yeah.. i missed that..  thank you so much for this clarification. Any suggestion on how can i test it better then?

Comment: @BlueEagle As soon as you start having static state, you're making testing a lot harder. You should almost never do it.

Comment: If you really need to have static field, then set it to `null` in `@AfterMethod`

Comment: @Nikem its a private member, ill have to expose a setter to achieve this, not something I am inclined to do.

Comment: @PaulBoddington since this is a common value used by all threads,  I thought making it static would be right pattern, thoughts?

Comment: You can make it an instance field of a singleton. For testing purposes you can then create a new instance in the set up.